# Access-Dynamic Forms

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, dynamic

I have a form "alpha", which I am trying to dynamically alter. My code currently is very simple:

```
Dim frm as Form
Dim strName as string

StrName="alpha"

Set frm = CreateForm(strName)
```

To then be able to `Createcontrol()` on the form dynamically..
but it seems I'm misunderstanding the function `CreateForm()` as it's giving me an error 7870 with regards to not finding the database "alpha".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.createform

The first parameter of `CreateForm` is `Database` - only use it to create the form in a different db.

To set the name:

```
Set frm = CreateForm()
frm.Name = strName
```

Or if "alpha" is your form template:

```
Set frm = CreateForm(FormTemplate:=strName)
```

---

To edit the design of the form, you simply open it in design view:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm strName, acDesign
Set frm = Forms(strName)   ' if you want to change form properties
Set ctl = CreateControl(strName, acTextBox, acDetail)
```

BUT: this is almost certainly not the best way to do what you want.

A better approach for dynamic forms is to have invisible controls already on the form, and make them visible (or vice versa) depending on conditions.

e.g. something like this:

```
For i = 1 to 12
    Me("month_" & i).Visible = (i <= curMonth)
Next i
```

Comment: So the template only gives me the size of the form...I actually want to "hold" alpha and build other things onto it.. So alpha already had a few text field on it. You know what I mean?